# ruby instance_eval will go stac level too deep when calling proc inside it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proc

I run into really interesting problem with ruby today. I have a  module/rails concern :

```
module BreakCacheModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern      

  module ClassMethods
    def breakable_cache_for(method_name, &block)
      method_name = method_name.to_sym
      set_breakable_cache_proc(method_name, block)
      define_breakable_cache_method(method_name)
    end

    def define_breakable_cache_method(method_name) 
      instance_eval(
        "def #{method_name}
          # here will be Rails.cache.fetch block around line below once I figure out this problem
          @_break_cache_procs[#{method_name}].call  # !!! this line will cause an issue
        end"
      )
    end

    def set_breakable_cache_proc(method_name, block)
      @_break_cache_procs ||={}
      @_break_cache_procs.merge!({method_name => block})
      @_break_cache_procs
    end
  end

end
```

and in my model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BreakCacheModule

  breakable_cache_for :all_client_ids do
    Client.pluck :id
  end
end
```

so sofar so good but once I go into console (Or run my spec) problems will show up

```
Client.all_client_ids 
# SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

but when I do:

```
Client.instance_variable_get("@_break_cache_procs")[:all_client_ids].call
#=> [1,2,3]
```

The functionality is exactly the same, only difference is that I'm not calling proc from instance_eval.

Am I missing something ??

my ruby ruby-2.0.0-p247 and Rails 3.2.14

Thank you for help

---

**Update after accepting**

Just to sum this up, I was getting actually this error from two places:

```
    "def #{method_name}
      Rails.cache.fetch(#{method_name.to_s}) do     # method_name should be in quotes
        @_break_cache_procs[#{method_name}].call    # missing colon ...look on answer 
      end
    end"
```

so the code should look like this

```
  instance_eval(
    "def #{method_name}
      Rails.cache.fetch('#{method_name.to_s}') do
        @_break_cache_procs[:#{method_name}].call
      end
    end"
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string passed to `instance_eval` is actually:

```
"def all_client_ids
  @_break_cache_procs[all_client_ids].call
end"
```

You may have noticed the problem: a colon is missing.

This should be the correct code:

```
def define_breakable_cache_method(method_name) 
  instance_eval(
    "def #{method_name}
      # here will be Rails.cache.fetch block around line below once I figure out this problem
      @_break_cache_procs[:#{method_name}].call  # !!! this line will cause an issue
    end"
  )
end
```

Comment: hi, yeah that was just my typo, but with or without the colon same result `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`  ...thx anyway

Comment: Really? To debug the problem, I think you can print out the string passed to `instance_eval`. This way it is easier to see the problem.

Comment: AAAAAA! I'm an idiot, yes you guys are right, it was due to colon. It wasn't working because previously when  I was trying it, I actually got same  error from `Rails.cache.fetch method_name` (I was passing method_name without wrapping it to apostrophes)